# How do I explain to the compiler that T implements Add in a way that returns the same type?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement `Add` for a simple generic type:

```
use std::ops::Add;

pub struct Vector2<T> {
    x: T,
    y: T,
}

impl<T> Vector2<T> {
    fn new(x: T, y: T) -> Self {
        Vector2::<T> { x, y }
    }
}

impl<T: Add> Add<Vector2<T>> for Vector2<T> {
    type Output = Vector2<T>;

    fn add(self, other: Vector2<T>) -> Vector2<T> {
        let x = self.x + other.x;
        let y = self.y + other.y;

        Vector2::<T> {
            x: self.x + other.x,
            y: self.y + other.y,
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the result:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:22:16
   |
22 |             x: self.x + other.x,
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter, found associated type
   |
   = note: expected type `T`
              found type `<T as std::ops::Add>::Output`
```

If I interpret this correctly, it's saying "You said you were giving me `T`, but instead all I have is the result of `T + T`, and I don't have visibility to know whether that is `T`."

How do I explain to the compiler that `T` not only implements `Add,` but it does so in a way that returns the same type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that a generic `T` + the same `T` is not necessarily `T`.

Your `Add` impl has to look something like this:

```
impl<T: Add> Add<Vector2<T>> for Vector2<T> {
    type Output = Vector2<<T as Add>::Output>;

    fn add(self, other: Vector2<T>) -> Self::Output {
        Vector2 {
            x: self.x + other.x,
            y: self.y + other.y,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah! I see now. Instead of convincing the compiler the result would be T, type the output to be flexible. Perfect. Thanks!